# Como escolher uma data e obter a semana e habilitar select com valores específicos

Tags: javascript, data

Será que podem me ajudar, pois estou "quebrando cabeça" a dias:

1. Ao clicar num input text é aberto um calendário e então escolho uma data;
2. Necessito que outro input text calcule o dia da semana (Terça ou Quinta somente) baseado na date escolhida
3. E através do input text do dia da semana, deverá ficar visibled o select para escolher o horário:
   TERÇA = 14:30, 14:50, 15:10, 15:30 e 15:40 e QUINTA = 09:40, 10:10, 10:30, 10:50 e 11:10

Estou tentando pegar a data com o `document.getElementById`, mas justamente neste campo Não acontece nada! Será por causa do calendário...

```
function escrever(el) {
    var isso = document.getElementById('calendSemana').value = el.value; 

    //var dias_semana = new Array("Domingo", "Segunda-feira", "Terça-feira", "Quarta-feira", "Quinta-feira", "Sexta-feira", "Sábado");
    //var data = new Date();
    //var dia = data.getDay();

    //document.write(dias_semana[dia]);

    //linhasOcultas = (dias_semana[dia]);

    //document.getElementById("#calendSemana").value(linhasOcultas);

    //var campoValor = document.getElementById("celular").value;
    //document.write(linhasOcultas);
    //document.getElementById('calendSemana').value += campoValor;

    //document.write("<input type='text' class='inputcad' id='calendSemana' name='calendSemana' maxlength='10' value='"+isso+"'>");

    //document.getElementById('#calendSemana').value = document.getElementById('#data_3').value;

    //document.getElementById('calendSemana').innerHTML = el.value;

}
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function mostraDiv(valor) {
          if(valor == "Terça")
          {
                document.getElementById("TER").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("QUI").style.display = "none";
          }
          else if(valor == "Quinta")
          {
                document.getElementById("TER").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("QUI").style.display = "block";
          }
          else if(valor == "Selecione")
          {
                document.getElementById("TER").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("QUI").style.display = "none";
          }
}
</script>

<select name='dia' id='dia' class='inputselec' onchange='mostraDiv(this.value)'>
<option value="<? echo $_SESSION['dia_c']; ?>"><? if(empty($_SESSION['dia_c'])) { echo "Selecione"; } else { echo $_SESSION['dia_c']; } ?></option>
<option value='Terça'>Terça-feira</option>      
<option value='Quinta'>Quinta-feira</option>
</select>

<div id='TER' style='display:none'>
<select name='terca' id='terca' class='inputselec'>
<option value="<? echo $_SESSION['terca_c']; ?>"><? if(empty($_SESSION['terca_c'])) { echo "Horário"; } else { echo $_SESSION['terca_c']; } ?></option>
<option value='14:30'>14:30</option>
<option value='14:50'>14:50</option>
<option value='15:10'>15:10</option>
<option value='15:30'>15:30</option>
<option value='15:40'>15:40</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id='QUI' style='display:<? echo $mostraQ ?>'>
<select name='quinta' class='inputselec'>
<option value="<? echo $_SESSION['quinta_c']; ?>"><? if(empty($_SESSION['quinta_c'])) { echo "Horário"; } else { echo $_SESSION['quinta_c']; } ?></option>
<option value='09:40'>09:40</option>
<option value='10:10'>10:10</option>
<option value='10:30'>10:30</option>
<option value='10:50'>10:50</option>
<option value='11:10'>11:10</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Agradeço muito a quem puder me ajudar... Luz e Paz!

Comment: Java? Não seria Javascript?

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow Português, por favor leia o [ask]. Tente incluir na sua pergunta o código que você tem.

Comment: Sim... Javascript... e eu só tenho tentavivas...

Comment: Olá Paulo, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Para que você possa obter a ajuda adequada, e para que o restante da comunidade possa se beneficiar do conteúdo postado, é importante que você crie um [MVCE](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Nós precisamos saber exatamente o que é esse calendário para te dar uma resposta específica. Dê uma olhada em [Como fazer uma boa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Uma das boas maneiras de fazer isso para JavaScript é clicar no botão `Trecho JavaScript/HTML/CSS` e colar o seu exemplo.

Comment: Como eu posso inserir os códigos do calendário? Obrigado!

Comment: Oi Paulo, clicando em editar você verá alguns botões em cima da caixa de texto. O sexto botão (com um símbolo de `<>`) permite a você colar seus trechos de código e gerar um exemplo executável do calendário.